# Absolute library dependency in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using Angular + Require for a project. When I try to package the application with r.js using:

```
node r.js -o app.build.config.js
```

Everything works except for the library files. Instead of looking for them on the provided path, the dependencies are being looked up relative to the folder I provide as a target.

```
({
    appDir: "C:/dev/etc/",
    baseUrl: "javascript/core/",
    dir: "app-build/",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "application",
            out: "app.js"
        }
    ],
    findNestedDependencies: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share the same configuration as used by your runtime code to find the location of your libraries (e.g. Angular), you can use the [mainConfigFile](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27) option:

> ...if you prefer the "main" JS file configuration to be read for the build so that you do not have to duplicate the values in a separate configuration, set this property to the location of that main JS file. The first requirejs({}), require({}), requirejs.config({}), or require.config({}) call found in that file will be used.

So your build config might look something like this:

```
({
    appDir: "C:/dev/etc/",
    baseUrl: "javascript/core/",
    mainConfigFile: 'c:/dev/etc/js/config.js', // whatever your file is called
    dir: "app-build/",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "application",
            out: "app.js"
        }
    ],
    findNestedDependencies: true
})
```

I had the same issue and the above solved it for me. Prior to adding the mainConfigFile line I would get something like this from the r.js optimizer:

> Tracing dependencies for: application
>   Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/some/path/app-build/jquery.js'
>   In module tree:
>   application`